# What does the syntax of '...' after the call to std::forward mean?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The function `std::forward` is declared like so:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;
```

Meaning it takes a single argument of type `std::remove_reference<T>::type&`.

However, `std::forward` can also be used with variadic arguments:

```
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args)
{
    q(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I understand variadic templates and unpacking them.

However, I don't understand the syntax of `...` coming "*after* " the call to `std::forward`.

What does this syntax mean precisely? Why does it work? Can it be used with functions other than `std::forward`?

Comment: Note that in your example `std::foward` provides no benefits.To achieve perfect forwarding you need [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) which would be `void f(Args&&... args)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what is called [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion).  It expands the parameter pack out with commas between each member of the pack so

```
q(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

says that for each member of the parameter pack `args` apply `std::forward` to it.  The resulting code would look like

```
q(std::forward<Args>(args1), std::forward<Args>(args2), ..., std::forward<Args>(argsN));
```

This works with any expression, it doesn't just apply to `std::forward`.  For instance you could add some value to each parameter like

```
q((args + 1)...);
```

and that would expand to

```
q((args1 + 1), (args2 + 1), ..., (argsN + 1));
```